# Modify pwpolicy in Sierra

Tags: macos, password

I am trying to modify default Sierra password policies through `pwpolicy`, trying for example, to lower the depth of password history from 24 to 1 by hitting as sudoer:

```
sudo pwpolicy setaccountpolicies "policyAttributePasswordHistoryDepth=1"
```

But it is not working. The error message is:

> Error: Policy file  not found

The policyIdentifier I try to change that gets listed (with many more) when hitting `pwpolicy getaccountpolicies` reads like this:

```
<key>policyIdentifier</key>             
<string>ProfilePayload:[HASHED_VALUE]:pinHistory</string>           
<key>policyParameters</key>             
<dict>
  <key>policyAttributePasswordHistoryDepth</key>
  <integer>24</integer>             
</dict>
```

How is the proper way of doing it?

Comment: I've never used the command, but according to the man page `-setaccountpolicies` "Takes one
                                  argument: the name of the file containing the policies."

Comment: I can't find the file nor the path for the XML list of policies. I am just able to get the through the 'pwpolicy' command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this is how I finally resolved it, though I am not sure if it is the properest way.

As [@patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/9058/patrix) pointed out, `pwpolicy setaccountpolicies` requires for the path of a XML file with the policies.

`pwpolicy getaccountpolicies` gives the current global policies in XML format, so I redirected the output to a file with
`pwpolicy getaccountpolicies > file.plist` , removing the possible info messages the command might write and leaving only the XML structure.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>policyCategoryPasswordChange</key>
    <array>
    ...
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then I changed the value I wanted to modify in my case, in the file I created (`file.plist`):

```
<key>policyIdentifier</key>             
<string>ProfilePayload:[HASHED_VALUE]:pinHistory</string>           
<key>policyParameters</key>             
<dict>
  <key>policyAttributePasswordHistoryDepth</key>
  <integer>2</integer>             
</dict>
```

Finally I used that file to update the policy:
`pwpolicy setaccountpolicies /path/to/file.plist`