# How to Set a Short User Password in macOS Mojave and Later (10.14+)

Tags: macos, command-line, mojave, catalina, password

I just installed macOS Mojave and put in my usual short desktop-only password I've been using for years (yes, you read that right). Now though, the operating system rejects setting a password less than 4 characters. It also does not allow having no password at all.

I am completely comfortable using the shell if need be.

How can I change the password policy to allow quite short passwords?

Comment: What about setting up with longer password and then changing to a short password with `passwd` command?

Comment: @JBis `passwd` outputs `passwd: authentication token failure` each time I attempt to change it to less than 4 characters. It works if I use 4 characters.

Comment: Great. Use 4 characters I will add answer and edit if I find better solution.

Comment: Found the answer please hold on the line while I transfer you....

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Optionally, learn a bit of the regular expression language - regex (this may take a while) and you can use the one crafted below for a 4 character length password. Here’s how to retrieve the configuration, edit that file, and then load it into the system:

1. `pwpolicy getaccountpolicies | awk 'NR>1' > ~/Desktop/file.plist`
2. `nano ~/Desktop/file.plist`
3. Change the quoted part to your Regex.

   ```
    policyAttributePassword matches '^$|.{4,}+'
   ```
4. `pwpolicy setaccountpolicies ~/Desktop/file.plist`
5. `passwd`

**Presets:**

- `^$|.{1,}+` : Any password. (Not the best Regex, but I didn't want to mess around with it too much.)

Confirmed this works with macOS Mojave (10.14).

Source: [Modify pwpolicy in Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/293820/modify-pwpolicy-in-sierra)

Comment: This no longer works in Mojave 10.14.4 (the `setaccountpolicies` gives an error about wrong format.) See answer from @david-p below for a working solution.

Comment: @Motsel Step 3.

Comment: ‍♂️

Comment: Looks like you duplicate the policy, then point system to look at the new policy file.  How do you revert?  (i.e., get the system to look at the default policy file).

Comment: David's solution works for me with Big Sur and is much easier

Comment: Not sure why this is getting downvotes. David P's is the better solution for this specific problem, but my solution works for the more general case of "I want to change the password policy"

Answer (score 93):

You can also use the much more straightforward command:

```
pwpolicy -clearaccountpolicies
```

to remove the 4-character requirement for all users.  The `man` page gives other useful examples if you want to change the policy on a per-user basis.

Comment: Worked for me, thanks! MacOS Mojave (10.14.2)

Comment: David P. thank you very much! this Mojave requirement was driving me crazy! This totally works! you can even set a password blank Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much! :D, I should keep that line in mind. now I can use my one letter password xD

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: this is the solution... the others are a "fix"...

Comment: Wowwww, its should CHECKED ANSWER