# How can I make my Mac accept a user password of less then 4 characters?

Tags: macos, password, mojave

I don't want secure password for my desktop. Instead I use just two letters for quick typing. I can change password in terminal by running:

```
passwd
```

But terminal gives me:   `Failed global policy "com.apple.defaultpasswordpolicy"  Password change failed because password does not meet minimum quality requirements`

[I believe if the password has less than 4 characters this is blocked.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337468/how-to-set-short-user-password-macos-mojave)
The same limitation is when trying to set it by preference panel obviously.

Until now in last versions of system, only solution I found was installing of Server application from Apple and basically modifying you osx by it to be   a server, so you can access one setting for password characters policy and be able to set whatever password you like. 
So is there other option ?

Comment: What are you actually running in Terminal to get that error? Might be worth adding, right now the question looks kind of incomplete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found this not so easy solution on web, that works quickly instead of necessity to do it by Server application from apple.

In Terminal:

```
pwpolicy getaccountpolicies > temp.xml
nano temp.xml
```

Now remove text prior to first `<xml` tag and replace

```
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '^$|.{4,}+'</string>
```

to

```
<string>policyAttributePassword matches '^$|.{1,}+'</string>
```

then save file (<kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>), exit (<kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd>) and run

```
sudo pwpolicy setaccountpolicies temp.xml
```

to install the updated policy.

Comment: It's always advisable to reduce the work done in an admin/root shell to a minimum. Luckily one can read the current policies without having to be root.

Comment: It works for me ! thanks a lot!   First: remove the one line,  Two: alter march rules!

Comment: I am getting now after some years Error: The data is not in the correct format. so looks like it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Worked for me in May 2023 on an old machine running macOS Catalina, thanks!

Comment: the generated template file adds a string on top, states something like "Getting global account policies", remove it while modifying the xml file, and it'll work fine